# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am getting the following error using discord.js V14 :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Thank you to anyone who can help me.

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('this is a test thing'),
    /**
    * @parom {Client} client
    * @parom {Message} message
    * @parom {String[]} args
    */
     async execute(client, message, args, interaction) {
        const questions = [
            "test",
            "test1?"
        ];
          
        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;
        
        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        const author = message.author;
        const appStart = await author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
        const channel = appStart.channel;
        
        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        message.delete({timeout: 100})

        collector.on("collect", () => {
            if (collectCounter < questions.length) {
                channel.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
            } else {
                channel.send("submited!");
                collector.stop("fulfilled");
            }
        });

        const appsChannel = client.channels.cache.get("976110575547482152");
        collector.on("end", (collected, reason) =>{
            if (reason === "fulfilled") {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected
                    .map((msg) => { 
                        return `${index++}) ${questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`;
                    })
                    .join("\n\n");
                        
                appsChannel.send(
                    new MessageEmbed()
                        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true}))
                        .setTitle("!New Report!")
                        .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
                        .setTimestamp()

                );
                appsChannel.send(`<@1057374161846145076>`);
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Note I was using this before and once I updated to V14 I started getting this error.
it should message the user the set questions then post the answers in a channel.

EDIT: I am getting the error on this line

```
const appStart = await author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
```

My interactions.js file

```
module.exports = {
    name: "interactionCreate",
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            const {commands} = client;
            const {commandName} = interaction;
            const command = commands.get(commandName);
            if (!command) return;

            try {
                await command.execute(interaction, client);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
              await interaction.reply({
                content: `Something went wrong while executing this command...`,
                ephemeral: true,
              });
                
            }
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
          const {buttons} = client;
          const {customId} = interaction;
          const button = buttons.get(customId);
          if (!button) return new Error('This Button Does not exist');

          try{
            await button.execute(interaction, client);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Maybe give info which .send throws the error

Comment: @JustinL Sorry adding that now its line `const appStart = await author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
`

Comment: Could you also add your file where you call the commands? Maybe a `interactionCreate.js` file?

Comment: Yes, Sorry @Caladan I've add it now.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the execute method of your `/test` command file with `(interaction, client)` but the method expects `(client, message, args, interaction)`.

A possible solution would be to change the `/test` command file to

```
// Optimized imports
const { Client, MessageEmbed, BaseInteraction,
     SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test')
        .setDescription('this is a test thing'),
    // Fixed typo in @param
    /**
    * @param {Client} client
    * @param {BaseInteraction} interaction
    */
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const questions = [
            "test",
            "test1?"
        ];

        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;

        // Get "Author" from interaction
        const author = interaction.user;
        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === author.id;
        const appStart = await author.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
        const channel = appStart.channel;

        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        // Removed message.delete() because interactions aren't messages and cant be deleted.

        collector.on("collect", () => {
            if (collectCounter < questions.length) {
                channel.send(questions[collectCounter++]);
            } else {
                channel.send("submited!");
                collector.stop("fulfilled");
            }
        });

        const appsChannel = client.channels.cache.get("976110575547482152");
        collector.on("end", (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason === "fulfilled") {
                let index = 1;
                const mappedResponses = collected
                    .map((msg) => {
                        return `${index++}) ${questions[endCounter++]}\n-> ${msg.content}`;
                    })
                    .join("\n\n");

                appsChannel.send(
                    new MessageEmbed()
                        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                        .setTitle("!New Report!")
                        .setDescription(mappedResponses)
                        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
                        .setTimestamp()

                );
                appsChannel.send(`<@1057374161846145076>`);
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. When I ran this command with this code the bot would send the first question in dm's once you respond to that question the bot would not send any message back and the bot would not log the message in the appsChannel.